# Annoying window opening each time I start Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have uninstalled some time ago an application, but since that, [this window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5F4tV.png) is always opening when I start my PC:

[image: Screenshot]

It asks me if I am sure I want to install it. It's annoying because (I am pretty sure) the app is already uninstalled. Do you know what can I do to stop this window from popping up each time I turn on the computer? Thanks!

Comment: This dialog is spawned by a technology called “ClickOnce”. Since it only appears when starting the PC, did you check the various autorun locations for leftovers yet?

Comment: I've just found this file on the Windows start up programs folder and deleted it... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, about the dialog. It’s from a technology called “ClickOnce”. It allows .NET software creators to offer their software to users without having to build an installer. When the user launches the software, it always goes through the ClickOnce to ensure updates are deployed etc.

Because the dialog appears when you start the PC, the program most likely remains at some autorun location. Because ClickOnce would detect the program isn’t currently installed, it will offer to install it.

Unfortunately, with ClickOnce deployment, there are no custom uninstall actions. As such, stuff outside of the standard ClickOnce locations will remain after uninstalling. This also includes the autorun entry.